# Do I need to check one by one to know which radiobutton is checked in a group in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, radio-button

I know that I can use this kind of code to know which radio button is checked in Qt:

```
int checkButton;
if( ui->radioButton_0->isChecked() ){
    checkButton = 0;
}else if(ui->radioButton_1->isChecked()){
    checkButton = 1;
}else if 
...
```

Are there any **easier** way to know which radio button is checked in a group in Qt. I think it is really helpful if there is such kind of easier way when the group of radio button is large. Code may look like that:

```
int checkbutton = groupName.getCheckButtonIngroup();
```

Comment: `QButtonGroup` has a function `buttons()` which returns a list of all buttons belonging to it. Can't you loop over that list? Reference: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html Also, if you just want the checked button, there is this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#checkedButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also we can put a few radiobuttons in groupbox in Qt Designer and after this find children of groupbox, add children to buttonGroup and use the checkedId or checkedButton methods.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_15_clicked()
{
    QButtonGroup group;
    QList<QRadioButton *> allButtons = ui->groupBox->findChildren<QRadioButton *>();
    qDebug() <<allButtons.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); ++i)
    {
        group.addButton(allButtons[i],i);
    }
    qDebug() << group.checkedId();
    qDebug() << group.checkedButton();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add all radio buttons to a button group. There are two ways to do that:

1. In Qt Designer select all radio buttons you want to add and select `Assign to button group` from the context menu.
2. From the code. Create a new QButtonGroup and add the buttons there with `QButtonGroup::addButton`.

Then anytime you can get to know what button is checked:

1. If you need a pointer of a checked button use `QButtonGroup::checkedButton`.
2. If you need a number of the button you need to add buttons to the group manually with `addButton(QAbstractButton* button, int id)`. After this use `QButtonGroup::checkedId` to get an identifier of the checked button.